# Abrir página após 2 segundos com js no intel xdk

Tags: javascript, intel-xdk

Estou usando o intel xdk.
Na primeira página tem a logo do sistema, quero que seja carregada a página inicial do sistema após 2s.

Como teste fiz isso com botão para saber como é feito, mas não estou sabendo fazer para que seja carregado automaticamente após 2s.

Veja:

```
$(document).on("click", ".uib_w_2", function(evt){
         activate_page("#inicio"); 
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Consegui!

Para quem tiver a mesma dúvida segue a resposta:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    activate_page("#inicio"); 
}, 2000) ;
```

Comment: Marque sua resposta como aceita